# Schedule a single-threaded repeating runnable in java, but skip the current run if previous run is not finished

Tags: java

Sometimes the duration of a repeated task is longer than its period (In my case, this can happen for hours at a time). Think of a repeated task that takes 7 minutes to run and is scheduled to run every 10 minutes, but sometimes takes 15 minutes for each run for a few hours in a row.

The Timer and ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor classes both have a scheduleAtFixedRate method that is usually used for this type of functionality. However, both have the characteristic that they 'try to catch up when they fall behind'. In other words, if a Timer falls behind by a few executions, it builds up a queue of work that will be worked on continuously until it catches back up to the number of runs that would have happened if none of the tasks had taken longer than the specified period. I want to avoid this behavior by skipping the current execution if the previous run is not complete.

I have one solution that involves messing around with the afterExecution method of a pooled executor, recalculating a delay, and rescheduling the runnable with the new delay, but was wondering if there's a simpler way, or if this functionality already exists in a common library somewhere. I know about scheduling with a fixed delay rather than a fixed period, but this will not work for me since it's important to try to execute the tasks at their fixed times. Are there any simpler options than my afterExecution solution?

Comment: Simplest is to have your task check if there is another instance already running, and, if so, immediately shoot itself.

Comment: @Hot Licks: ScheduledExecutorService doesn't actually run them in parallel though.

Comment: So what's the key requirement here?  That it only and always starts on **a** 10-minute interval, regardless of whether it missed one?  If so you're not talking about a rate.

Comment: @MarkPeters -- I don't see a requirement to use ScheduledExecutorService.

Comment: @HotLicks: Fair enough, in your suggestion how is the task being scheduled? (OP is using a ScheduledExecutorService currently)

Comment: I found a very similar question with a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864838/supressing-redundant-jobs-in-scheduledthreadpoolexecutor

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think what you want is for the long-running task itself to not run in the ScheduledExecutorService itself, but in a background thread.  Then the fixed-rate task will always complete quickly, since it is only used for checking whether to start the actual task in the background (or not, if it's still running from last time).

```
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
final Runnable actualTask = null;

executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private Future<?> lastExecution;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (lastExecution != null && !lastExecution.isDone()) {
            return;
        }
        lastExecution = executor.submit(actualTask);
    }
}, 10, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: @jonderry: Sorry, missed your last sentence.  I've got a couple of other ideas, not sure if they'll be any cleaner.

Comment: @jonderry: Ok I think the latest suggestion I posted is a good one.  I cleaned up my answer, you can see the edit history for the other suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, this looks slightly cleaner than my solution.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `scheduleWithFixedDelay` method instead. It's similar but this one does not have a queue for missed runs and instead starts counting again only when the current Runnable was terminated.

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) states the reexecution of the Runnable will be scheduled based on the delay parameter:

> The delay between the termination of one execution and the commencement of the next.

Answer (score 1):

Make a third class, say called Coordinator. Coordinator has a synchronized startRunning() method which sets isRunning to true and returns true if another thread was not running already. There should also be a synchronized stopRunning method which sets isRunning to false. It returns true if a runnable is already running. You make a single instance of this class and pass a reference to all of the runnables you construct. In the runnable's run method you first call startRunning and check the return to verify that another one isn't running already. Make sure to put the code in run() in a try-finally and call stopRunning from within the finally block.